# How to find certain elements in a HTML string without jQuery or ID

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a code in Javascript without the use of jQuery to find and output out the contents of `California condor`, which should print `Critically Endangered` in the console. However, I'm not sure how to do this correctly, especially without the use of jQuery. Can anyone help or give me some tips?

```
document.body.innerHTML =
`<div>
  <ul data-continent="North America">
    <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
    <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
  </ul>
  <ul data-continent="Europe">
    <li data-species="Cave bear">Extinct</li>
  </ul>
</div>`;

function code() {
  return document.body.innerHTML.getElementsByTagName('ul data-continent="North America"').getElementsByTagName('li data-species="California condor"');

console.log(code())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    document.body.innerHTML =
    `<div>
    <ul data-continent="North America">
        <li data-species="California condor">Critically Endangered</li>
        <li data-species="American bison">Near Threatened</li>
    </ul>
    <ul data-continent="Europe">
        <li data-species="Cave bear">Extinct</li>
    </ul>
    </div>`;

    function code() {
        return document.querySelector('li[data-species="California condor"]').innerHTML
    }
    console.log(code())
</script>
```